# keyCode 13 not working

Tags: javascript, css, keycode

I have developed a search feature in my application. Users can search for streets by typing the address in an input box. Onkeyup, the a function is called that compares the input against a database full of addresses. The function gives back 5 suggestions which are showed below the inputbox like a sort of dropdownmenu. This works perfectly fine. The user can afterwards select one of the suggestions, which triggers another function.

What I want to implement now is that, when the user presses ENTER, the second function is automatically called with the first suggestion. I thought it would not be that difficult to program, but I'm facing some difficulties. When I press enter, the page refreshes instead of going to the function.

Here is my code:

```
<div id = "toolbar">
<form id ="suggestions">
    <input type = "text" id = "insertText" autocomplete="off" onkeyup = "if(event.keyCode == 13) {SearchAddress(option1.text)} else {giveSuggestion()}" onfocus='showOptions()'
    <option class="option" id = "option1" onmousedown = "searchAddress(option1.text)"></option>
    <option class="option" id = "option2" ... </option>
</form>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#toolbar {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 25px;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        padding: 5px 10px;
        background: #ccc;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #333;
    }
#suggestions {
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        position: absolute;
        left: 310px;
        top: 5px;
        background-color: white;
        font-size: 12px;
    }
.option{
        display:none;
        cursor: default;
        padding: 0px 3px;
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your code is incorrect, as far as I can see already.

Comment: _"the page refreshes"_ -> technically the form is submitting, and hasn't got an action, so it sends it back to the same page, causing it to reload.

Comment: You forget to close input tag. use event.preventDefault();

Comment: Lose the inline JavaScript! It's almost 2016 god damn it!

Comment: @Iulian Onofrei language!! Use your words...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hit `enter` the browser tries to submit the form.

So, there are two possible solutions:

1. Remove form tag, if you don't need to send any data from it to the backend.
2. Add `onsubmit="return false;"` to the form tag.

Comment: Thanks! Guess I didn't know what a form-tag did...

Comment: Thanks for the solution. In my case I had used e.keycode instead of e.keyCode. Missed Camel Case (camelCase).

Answer (score 0):

I guess the browser didn't know what event is So......

```
<input type = "text" 
       id = "insertText"
       autocomplete="off" 
       onkeyup = "function(event){if(event.keyCode == 13) 
                                    {SearchAddress(option1.text)} 
                                  else {giveSuggestion()}"
       onfocus='showOptions()'}" />
```

Comment: The browser know the event [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jnwrc5ay/5/).

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior of form will refresh the page, so place replace the form tag to div, and handle the form submit yourself use library like jQuery or vanilla **XMLHttpRequest** object.